# Join with update statement in plsql

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have two tables in oracle, `tblCustomer`,`tblCustomerShop` i have `Customer_id,Group_id` columns in `tblCustomer` and `Customer_id` column in  `tblCustomerShop` and i want to update only those records of `tblCustomerShop` where customer has `group_id =5`, any help plz?

Comment: Help yourself first by trying a query, and including that in your question.

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery here as:

```
update tblCustomerShop set <<whatever you want to update>> where Customer_id in 
(select Customer_id from tblCustomer where group_id=5);
```